# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path:

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, angular4-forms

I am leveraging Angular 4's FormBuilder and FormGroup class to create a Form. The form's content is supplied by a GET call with the Questions and Answers structured via JSON format.

Dabbling with my localhost, I see the following error from my web console on page load:

[image]

Could anyone with Angular Forms expertise correct this implementation and explain where I went wrong?

**Web Console** indicates this node from the HTML is causing it:

```
<fieldset [formGroupName]="i">
```

For sake of brevity, I'm just providing the bare-bone snippets only down below. Let me know if you need more details.

**HTML component:**

```
<form id="form-clinicalscreener" [formGroup]="clinicalForm" (submit)="submitScreenerForm(clinicalForm)" novalidate>
<div formArrayName="Questions">
<div class="section" *ngFor="let tab of clinicalQuestionsResults; let i = index;">
    <h2 class="form-title">{{tab.DisplayText}}</h2>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let question of tab.Questions">
            <fieldset [formGroupName]="i">
                <label>{{question.DisplayText}}</label>
                <input type="hidden" formControlName="QuestionId" value="{{question.Id}}" data-value="{{question.Id}}">
                <div [ngSwitch]="question.AnswerType">
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Radio'" class="form-group-answers">
                        <div class="radio" *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers">                               
                            <input type="radio" 
                                formControlName="AnswerId" 
                                value="{{answer.Id}}" 
                                data-value="{{answer.Id}}" 
                                class="radio-clinicalscreener">
                            <label class="label-answer">
                                <span class="label-answer-text">{{answer.DisplayText}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'DropDown'" class="form-group-answers">
                        <select formControlName="AnswerId" class="form-control">
                            <option value="{{answer.Id}}" data-value="{{answer.Id}}" *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers">{{answer.DisplayText}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-screener" type="submit" [disabled]="!clinicalForm.valid">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**TypeScript component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: '',
templateUrl: '',
styleUrls: ['']
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
// Our model driven form.
clinicalForm: FormGroup;

// Screener Data from API call to be used by view in for loop.
clinicalQuestionsResults: any;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    // Let's get Clinical Screener metadata.
    this.loadClinicalScreener();

    // Initialize the form here.
    this.clinicalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        Questions: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.initQuestions()
        ])
    });
}

private initQuestions() {
    // initialize our Questions
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        QuestionId: [''],
        AnswerId: ['']
    });
}

private loadClinicalScreener() {
    // An AJAX call from a forkJoin() to return the JSON payload, then I assign it to a local object, screenerResponse. 
    let screenerResponse: any = data[0];
    this.clinicalQuestionsResults = screenerResponse.Result.Tabs;
    console.log('Here is the metadata for Clinical Screener --->', this.clinicalQuestionsResults);
}
```

}

Comment: From the error it seems that you call the Group name by the index 'i' from your HTML, but in the initialize you are calling it 'Questions'

Comment: You registered only one group in your Questions FormArray but iterate over many results

Comment: @yurzui Please clarify? Do I need to modify initQuestions() to reflect your suggestion?

Comment: Angular doesn't create items in FormArray itself. You should handle it by hand. Now you have `Questions: [{ QuestionId, AnswerId} ]` and loop over Tabs which is not Questions at all.but rather array of objects with Questions array `Tabs:[{ Questions }, { Questions}, {Questions}]`

Comment: Hmmm...handle it by hand. I don't necessarily need to create items since the Questions and Answers (e.g. items) are already supplied by the back-end call. Would it be more prudent to just attach this to a model and just use a change event on the input and select elements to assign the correct QuestionId and AnswerId?